# How to change the Range interval in x and y axis in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

Below is my Data of which I am using Mathematica to plot graph.

```
f[x_] := {x, Sqrt[2/(3 x)]};

ListLinePlot[f /@ {2, 10, 100, 10^4, 10^7}]
```

But If I increase the x axis range beyond 10^7, then It becomes straight line and almost became horizontal with x axis so it can't be distinguished. So I was trying to increase the range of x axis for now I have range of 5000-10000, I would lIke to decrease it into interval of 1000 i.e 5000-6000 and 6000-7000 and so on.

Similary HOw can I change range of y axis too.

Below is my Graph of above plot

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html

Comment: consider using a log plot `ListLogPlot` or `ListLogLogPlot`